# How to calculate and extract prices from timestamps in R

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns, calculation

I have data for commodity price as you see in the table below:

```
Date      Time         Price
19990104  14:11:14.34  220 
19990104  14:11:21.21  200 
19990104  14:11:36.35  221  
19990104  14:11:45.45  202  
19990104  14:11:56.11  215
```

You see the time is 14h 11m and x seconds, with.xx milliseconds. I m trying to find the first value, the last value, the highest and the lowest value given in a minute. I have data for thousands of days and minutes, above is just an extract.

As a result I want to create a row with all the information.
For the table above the result should be:

```
Date     Time      Start End  Low High
19990104 14:11:00  220   215  200 221
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front, it might be a better path to convert your `Date` and `Time` fields into a single `POSIXt`-class object. This would be a good method if you have need for Date+Time to be a numeric-like field at some point (e.g., plotting something over time). It's not required, but in my experience I almost always have need to treat time numerically (and date usually needs to be there too).

If you don't want/need to change to `POSIXt` or `Time` class, you can do the below. (I added a couple of data rows in order to show multiple summary rows.)

### base R

```r
dat$min <- substr(dat$Time, 1, 5)
aggregate(dat$Price, dat[,c("Date","min")], function(Price) c(Start=Price[1], End=Price[length(Price)], Low=min(Price), High=max(Price)))
#       Date   min x.Start x.End x.Low x.High
# 1 19990104 14:11     220   215   200    221
# 2 19990104 14:12     229   209   209    229
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  arrange(Date, Time) %>%
  group_by(Date, min = substr(dat$Time, 1, 5)) %>%
  summarize(Time = min(Time), Start = first(Price), End = last(Price), Low = min(Price), High = max(Price)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-min)
# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#       Date Time     Start   End   Low  High
#      <int> <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 19990104 14:11:14   220   215   200   221
# 2 19990104 14:12:14   229   209   209   229
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Date = c(19990104L, 19990104L, 19990104L, 19990104L, 19990104L, 19990104L, 19990104L), Time = c("14:11:14", "14:11:21", "14:11:36", "14:11:45", "14:11:56", "14:12:14", "14:12:21"),     Price = c(220L, 200L, 221L, 202L, 215L, 229L, 209L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Date,      ~Time,      ~Price,
19990104,  "14:11:14", 220, 
19990104,  "14:11:21",  200, 
19990104,  "14:11:36", 221,  
19990104,  "14:11:45",  202 , 
19990104,  "14:11:56", 215)  

library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(hms = hms(Time), 
         hour = hour(hms), 
         minute = minute(hms), 
         Time = hm(paste(hour, minute, sep=":"))) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Time) %>% 
  summarise(Start = first(Price), 
            End = last(Price), 
            Low = min(Price), 
            High = max(Price)) 

# `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Date'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# # A tibble: 1 x 6
# # Groups:   Date [1]
#       Date Time       Start   End   Low  High
#      <dbl> <Period>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  
# 1 19990104 14H 11M 0S   220   215   200   221
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late response! The code worked but I made a little mistake in my example in the beginning, I already changede it as you can see above. I have a time like `14:11:05.23`. So I not only have seconds but also milliseconds, but I want the same output as you have in your solution. To remove the milliseconds and have 0 seconds. Do you have any idea here?

Answer (score 1):

1. First make the dataframe to work with from your example (`d`)
2. Then, extract the hours, minutes, and seconds using regular expressions
3. Finally, use summarize() on the grouped and arranged data to get the output you want

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

d <- tribble(
  ~Date,      ~Time,      ~Price,
  19990104,  "14:11:14",  220, 
  19990104,  "14:11:21",  200, 
  19990104,  "14:11:36",  221,  
  19990104,  "14:11:45",  202,  
  19990104,  "14:11:56",  215 
)


d %>%
  mutate(hour = gsub("^([0-9]{2}):.*$", "\\1", Time),
         minute = gsub("^.*:([0-9]{2}):.*$", "\\1", Time),
         seconds = gsub("^.*:.*:([0-9]{2})$", "\\1", Time),
         totalseconds = (as.numeric(hour) * 60 * 60) + (as.numeric(minute) * 60) + as.numeric(seconds)) %>%
  group_by(Date, hour, minute) %>%
  arrange(Date, hour, minute, seconds) %>%
  summarize(Start = first(Price),
            End = last(Price),
            Low = min(Price),
            High = max(Price)) %>%
  mutate(Time = paste0(hour, ":", minute, ":00")) %>%
  select(-hour, -minute) %>%
  relocate(Time, .before = Start)
```

Answer (score 1):

`to.minutes` in the quantmod package does this.  Assuming `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, convert it to a zoo object, use `to.minutes` to perform the desired calculation giving `zm` and round the minutes down giving `zm0`.  At the end we convert it to a data frame using `fortify.zoo`; however, you might want to leave it as `zm0` to simplify using the other facilities of quantmod and zoo.  Note that quantmod provides extraction functions: Hi, Lo, Op and Cl and also provides functions to plot OHLC series.

```
library(quantmod) # also loads zoo 
library(lubridate)

# this requires R 4.1.  Replace \ with the word function if
#   you have an old version of R    
z <- read.zoo(DF, index = 1:2, FUN = \(d, t) ymd_hms(paste(d, t)))

zm <- to.minutes(z)
zm0 <- aggregate(zm, floor_date(time(zm), "min"))

DF2 <- fortify.zoo(zm0); DF2
##                 Index z.Open z.High z.Low z.Close
## 1 1999-01-04 14:11:00    220    221   200     215

Cl(DF2)
## [1] 215
```

### Versions used

```
R.version.string
## [1] "R version 4.1.1 Patched (2021-08-10 r80733)"

packageVersion("quantmod")
## [1] ‘0.4.18’

packageVersion("zoo")
## [1] ‘1.8.9’

packageVersion("lubridate")
## [1] ‘1.7.10’
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Date      Time      Price
19990104  14:11:14  220 
19990104  14:11:21  200 
19990104  14:11:36  221  
19990104  14:11:45  202  
19990104  14:11:56  215  "

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I am quite unsure what is meant with `z <- read.zoo(DF, index = 1:2, FUN = \(d, t) ymd_hms(paste(d, t)))` What is the index here, and what does FUN mean? Got the message: "Error unexpected inpunt in z"

Comment: A zoo object is a vector or matrix with an attribute giving the time index and having a class of "zoo".  `read.zoo` converts `DF` to a zoo series with a POSIXct time index using the first two columns of `DF` to create that index.  See `?read.zoo` and the 5 vignettes  and reference manual that come with zoo for more information.  One of the vignettes is entirely focused on `read.zoo` .

Comment: It gives no errors with the data in the Note so you must have introduced an error somewhere but without knowing what you did it is difficult to address.

Comment: Thx, but the `d,  t` in the brackets, are these also to values I need to use or do I have to put my own in there instead?

Comment: With `DF <- structure(list(Date = c(19990104L, 19990104L, 19990104L, 19990104L, 
19990104L), Time = c("14:11:14.34", "14:11:21.21", "14:11:36.35", 
"14:11:45.45", "14:11:56.11"), Price = c(220L, 200L, 221L, 202L, 
215L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))` the code in the answer still works.

Answer (score 0):

The package dplyr should be able to help you here. Assuming the data is sorted first by Date and Time, the following piece of code should be able to group the data the way you want:

```
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(Date = rep("19990104", 5),
                  Time = c("14:11:14", "14:11:21", "14:11:36", "14:11:45", "14:11:56"),
                  Price = c(220, 200, 221, 202, 215),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)


data_processed = data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Time_min = paste(substr(Time, start = 1, stop = 5), "00", sep = ":"))

data_summary <- data_processed %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Date, Time_min) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Start = dplyr::first(Price),
                   End = dplyr::last(Price),
                   Low = min(Price, na.rm = T),
                   High = max(Price, na.rm = T))
```